# MinimalModbus read_registry error

Tags: python, modbus, minimalmodbus

I am trying to read registry information from a modbus device using MinimalModbus. However, every time I attempt to read registry `40003` which has a value of `220` I receive this error:

```
raise ValueError('The slave is indicating an error. The response is: {!r}'.format(response))
ValueError: The slave is indicating an error. The response is: '\x01\x83\x02Àñ'
```

I know there is a value in `40003` and I am following the communication documents for the device. Here is my code:

```
import minimalmodbus
import serial


gas = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM5', 1)
gas.serial.baudrate = 9600  
gas.serial.bytesize = 8
gas.serial.parity   = serial.PARITY_NONE
gas.serial.stopbits = 1
gas.serial.timeout  = 0.05   
gas.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU  


temp = gas.read_register(40003, 1)
print (float(temp))
```

I have this problem for every registry and I cannot find information regarding `Àñ`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the registry number `40003`. I guess the modbus protocol doesn't require the full registry number, so I changed it to `temp = gas.read_register(3, 1)`